# Write a binary downloaded file to disk in Java

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

I have a software that allow to write add-on in javascript files (.js) that allow to use Java function (I don't know if this is common, I never saw java call in javascript file before)

I need to download a binary file from a webserver and write it to the hard drive. I tried the following code:

```
baseencoder = new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64();
url = new java.net.URL("https://server/file.tgz");

urlConnect = url.openConnection();
urlConnect.setDoInput(true);
urlConnect.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnect.setRequestProperty("authorization","Basic "+ java.lang.String(baseencoder.encodeBase64(java.lang.String( username + ":" + password ).getBytes())));
urlConnect.setRequestProperty("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

is = new java.io.DataInputStream(urlConnect.getInputStream());
fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\tmp\\test.tgz");
out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
while((data = is.read()) != -1){
    out.write(data);
}

out.close();
is.close();
```

The resulting file is no longer a valid gzip archive. I'm sorry if I did a huge error but I'm not a programmer and don't know Java too much.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Don't use a [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) - that's trying to convert the data into text.

Just use `FileOutputStream`.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];

InputStream input = urlConnect.getInputStream();
try {
  OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filename);
  try {
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
  } finally {
    output.close();
  }
} finally {
  input.close();
}
```

Comment: Also, you'll want to use the correct test condition in your while loop: while((data = **is**.read()) != null){ ... }.

Comment: Thanks using a FileOutputStream works (i still use only a simple read() because it seems that it's not possible to use a byte buffer in javascript as it's not an object.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is already answered, but a simpler approach is to use Apache Commons IO's `IOUtils.copy()` method, which can fully copy an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

`DataInputStream` is meant for reading Java primitives, not for generic data.

It's also redundant, as `urlConnect.getInputStream();` already returns an InputStream, and all InputStreams support read().

```
is = urlConnect.getInputStream();
```

P.S. This is assuming `is` and `bis` are the same variable.  Otherwise, you're reading the wrong stream in the loop.

Comment: Nice Information! Interesting to learn that despite what the naming suggest DataInputStream isn't for generic data..!

Answer (score 0):

Just read about LimitInputStream sounds like it does exactly what you are doing, buffering the input stream for greater efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use NIO FileChannel#transferFrom method.

```
            URL website = new URL(urlToDownload);

            try (ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);) {
                fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            }
```

Reference [link1](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2022/07/how-to-download-binary-file-in-java.html), [link2](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2014/08/download-file-from-internet-using-java.html)